# Unexpected behaviour when Spock datatable's header contains variable named like variable in the other feature method

Tags: groovy, spock

I have a problem with data-driven tests in Spock.
When datatable header contains variable (in this case 'b') named like variable in the other feature method, the following exception is thrown:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object '3' with class 'java.lang.Integer' to class 'java.util.UUID'
```

Example specification class:

```
class ExampleSpec extends Specification {

    def 'example feature with variable named like datatable header'() {
        given:
        UUID b = UUID.randomUUID()

        when:
        def length = b.toString().length()

        then:
        length == 36
    }

    def "maximum of two numbers"() {
        expect:
        Math.max(a, b) == c

        where:
        a | b | c
        1 | 3 | 3
        0 | 0 | 0
    }
}
```

Does anyone know what the reason is that datatable's header variable interferes in such an unexpected way with a variable defined in the previous feature method?

The problem occurs only in version: '1.x-groovy-2.5'.

Comment: Not sure why it's apparently conflicting, but that's an invalid spec. The uuid test is expecting an assignment, not a comparison

Comment: Thanks, I have updated example, but it doesn't change anything according to the main question.

Comment: What version of groovy are you using?

Comment: I am using groovy in version 2.5.7

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing...  Did a search in Spock, and found there's an issue with the Groovy 2.5 compiler that seems to have caused this https://github.com/spockframework/spock/issues/880 which is still on-going...  Looks like a rename is the only way round it, and hopefully this is fixed in groovy 3...  I'm going to give it a go now, and check

Comment: Nope...I'm seeing the same in Groovy 3.0-beta-3 

Comment: @tim_yates, good to know this is a bug. I had thought it was simply an effect of [Sharing of Objects between Iterations](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.3/data_driven_testing.html#_sharing_of_objects_between_iterations).

Comment: Update: The Spock issue has been resolved after accepting a pull request, so the issue will be fixed in Spock 2.0 or the next milestone release, if any. I retested the current Spock master with your test.